# laravel one to many relation model use Laravel form builder example please

Tags: laravel, forms, laravel-5

laravel one to many relation model use [Laravel-form-builder](https://kristijanhusak.github.io/laravel-form-builder/) example. I have below one to many relation model

```
car_type model (one)
'id',
'name'

cars model (many)
'id',
'car_type_id',
'name'
```

I have already read [documentation](https://kristijanhusak.github.io/laravel-form-builder/field/collection.html) but I do not understand. Can you give me a full example?

Answer (score 0):

The proper documentation for that is here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Each car_type (I call this the car `make`) has cars. (e.g. There are millions of Toyota Camrys) This cars() method would then retrieve all of those related car models based on the car `make` (car_type). A car only has one type (e.g. a car can't be both a Toyota Camry and a Ford Focus), so the type() method on the cars model will retrieve the make of the car model.

```
class car_type extends Model {
    public function cars() {
        return $this->hasMany(cars::class);
    }
}

class cars extends Model {
    public function type() {
        return $this->belongsTo(car_type::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I also suggest changing your classes from snake case to camel case.

car_type -> CarType or Type or Make &
cars -> Car (singular is more appropriate than plural since the model represents a single car, while the collection is a group of cars).

Comment: thany you suggest,I will change to CardType and Car
However,
my problem is use Laravel-form-builder to make a one to many relation model form and save it

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your program logic would be, but the information in the form that would relate these two is simply the CarType's id. You Car model should have car_type_id that points to a CarType model. When creating a car model, you would simply just store the id of the CarType you have selected for that car.